# $_GET["foo"] NULL from RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect http://localhost/tour/hello to http://localhost/tour.php?name=hello

I have tried the following in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tour/(.+)/?$
RewriteRule ^tour/(.+)/?$ tour.php?name=$1 [L,QSA, NC]
```

It redirects to http://localhost/tour.php but $_GET["name"] is always NULL

if I change the target page to anything other than tour.php it works

```
RewriteRule ^tour/(.+)/?$    handler.php?name=$1 
RewriteRule ^tour/(.+)/?$    blah.php?name=$1
```

All work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable [content negociation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/content-negotiation.html) by:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

In your .htaccess.

And `AcceptPathInfo off`.

Some explanations:

The first issue is content negociation. Say you have two files named tour.txt and tour.php, if content negociation is enabled, if your URL is just http://localhost/tour, without extension, Apache is looking for files named tour with any extension and based on client preferences (in particular the Accept HTTP header for this example), will try to find the best match among tour.txt and tour.php to serve to the client.

The second element with your issue is AcceptPathInfo: when enabled, Apache accepts the superfluous part at the end of the path of the URL to populate it as an internal variable (the well known `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` in PHP for example). To illustrate, let's say you have a file tour.php. So, with `AcceptPathInfo on`, http://localhost/tour.php/extra/path invokes tour.php with `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` = /extra/path instead being considered as inexistant (404) as usually expected/with `AcceptPathInfo off`.

Now, combine both, AcceptPathInfo and content negociation: the problem is that your rule try to "intercept" what begins with tour/ but tour.php exists [is a file] so it conflicts with your own rule since the path tour/foo [for the URL http://localhost/tour/foo] is first resolved by the content negociation as tour.php/foo and "accepted" as tour.php with `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` = /foo thanks to AcceptPathInfo. Conclusion: in this very specific case, no rewriting happened but it looks so because of content negociation + AcceptPathinfo which kind have the same effect by landing on tour.php and this is why you don't get the query string you were expecting (name=foo).

Also note there shouldn't be any space before NC flag in your rule.